# outerHeight() - не определяет высоту элемента

Tags: центрирование

Динамически, через скрипт, создаю модальное окно:

```
$('body').append('<div class="aw-modal-overlay" id="aw-overlay-' + modalid + '"><div class="aw-modal" style="width: ' + set.width +'px;" id="aw-modal-' + modalid + '"></div></div>');
var heightElement = $('#aw-modal-' + modalid).outerHeight();
```

Переменная heightElement = 0. Но высота модального окна не равна нулю.
Почему не определяется высота?

Полная рабочая версия скрипта в примере: http://architec.3440.aqq.ru/aw-content/aw-style/aw-modal-style.html

Хочу заставить центрироваться блок по высоте окна браузера. Если привязываю расчет положения модального окна к .resize()? то после срабатывания ресайза все центруется правильно...

Центрирую модальное окно так:

```
$(window).resize(function()
    {
        var heightElement = $('#aw-modal-' + modalid).outerHeight();
        console.log('Высота: ' + heightElement);

        $('#aw-modal-' + modalid).css
        ({
            position:'absolute',
            left: ($(window).width() - $('#aw-modal-' + modalid).outerWidth())/2,
            top: ($(window).height() - $('#aw-modal-' + modalid).outerHeight())/2
        });
    });
    $(window).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден!
Поскольку блок, высоту которого я хочу получить, является скрытым, т.е. dysplay = none, то определить высоту такого объекта невозможно.